# How to add date in MySQL when my column name is date?

Tags: mysql, syntax

H

```
CREATE TABLE `order`(
    order_id     INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id  INT         NOT NULL,
    agent_id     INT         NOT NULL,
    date         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

HERE IS MY SCRIPT

Comment: Why is your `date` column typed as `varchar(50)` and not the `date` data-type?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Using `date` as a column name doesn't prevent using dates. If you want to use the `date` function, it has `()` after it, and this prevents confusing it with the column name.

Comment: how to add date? Like the script to insert a date. My column name is date itself. I don't really know what to type in the date.

Comment: Backticks are recommended if the column name is a key/reserved word. Try `\`date\` date  NOT NULL`

Comment: You can learn more about date on the [official website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @blabla_bingo Backticks are a MySQL-extension. We should be using double-quotes as per ISO SQL. All major RDBMS support using double-quotes for nontrivial and escaped identifiers.

Comment: @Dai Well, I tried it in 5.7 and 8.0. Neither works.`mysql> create table nm ("id" int);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"id" int)' at line 1
mysql> create table nm (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)`

Comment: @blabla_bingo Use `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';` ([docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#ansi_quotes))

Comment: 'HERE IS MY SCRIPT' - nope that's a partial script lacking (amongst possible other things) a closing bracket and terminator and since you have an auto_increment column you have to tell mysql order_id is a primary key (or part of a compound key)

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the comments above telling you that you need to delimit the word `date`, they're wrong. `date` is not a reserved keyword in MySQL. You can name a column `date` easily, just as it is.

The confusion is that there's a difference between *reserved* keywords and *nonreserved* keywords. Reserved keywords require the delimiters if you want to use them as identifiers. The delimiters are optional for nonreserved keywords, or any other identifier.

`order` is a reserved keyword, therefore you need to delimit it.

This is explained on the manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

> Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting. Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”

That manual page also notes which keywords are reserved keywords with a "(R)" following them.

I tested your example CREATE TABLE statement, but I notice that it is incomplete. You have to finish it:

```
CREATE TABLE `order`(
  order_id     INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_id  INT         NOT NULL,
  agent_id     INT         NOT NULL,
  date         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);
```